# Segmentation fault after program finishes

Tags: c, gcc

I'm working on a homework assignment and I'm relatively new to C. I have to create an initializer for an array of integers.

The declarations given to me by my professor are:

```
typedef int set_t;    // Can't be altered
...
void init(set_t *thing, int N) {}    // Can't be altered
...
int main() {
    set_t a;         // Can't be altered
    init(&a, 10);    // Can't be altered
    return 0;
}
```

The initializer is supposed to allocate space a N elements in array `set_t a;`

Here is the code for my initializer:

```
void init(set_t *thing, int N) {

    *thing = *(set_t *)malloc(sizeof(set_t)*N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i = i + 1) {
        *(thing+i) = i;
    }
    return;
}
```

Everything compiles just fine but when I run it, the entire program runs and then I get a segmentation fault (In my copy of this code I have a bunch of print statements that run, hence how I know it runs through the entire program before I get the seg fault).

Any direction on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: at what line does it throw segfault?

Comment: I'm not sure, the only thing it says is `Segmentation fault: 11`

Edit: I've been trying to run GDB on it but I've been having issues with the codesigning so it hasn't been working

Comment: `The initializer is supposed to allocate space a N elements in array set_t a;` this is pretty ridiculous. Part of the premise that is forbidden to change is wrong. It makes sense that the answer of @dasblinkenlight.

Comment: I concur... its quite ridiculous :-/

Comment: See [Convert a non-pointer variable to a pointer to an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705010/convert-a-non-pointer-variable-to-a-pointer-to-an-array) for more background information on the question, though that question was asked after this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Professor realized that he had made an error in the assignment and fixed it. Changed `set_t a` to `set_a *a`.

Thanks for all your help (hope I didn't cause too many headaches!

Answer (score 3):

This line is wrong:

```
*thing = *(set_t *)malloc(sizeof(set_t)*N);
//       ^
//       |
// Here is the problem!
```

`malloc` allocates *uninitialized* memory, so defererencing it right away is undefined behavior. The program may crash right away, or it may crash after some time; in your case, it looks like the problem manifests itself later on.

Here is how to fix this: you need a double pointer. The best thing would be to `typedef` `set_t` as `int*`, but since it couldn't be altered, you could use `set_t**` in your function:

```
void init(set_t **thing, int N) {
    *thing = malloc(sizeof(set_t)*N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i = i + 1) {
        (*thing)[i] = i;
    }
}
```

You would need to call it like this:

```
set_t *a;
init(&a, 10);
```

Comment: I'm unable to change `set_t a;` to `set_t *a;` or the function declaration for init as per the assignment instructions (it would be a lot easier if I could :-) )

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
*thing = *(set_t *)malloc(sizeof(set_t)*N);
```

`thing` is a pointer-to-int.  `malloc` returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  So, you probably want to assign that pointer to `thing` (which is a pointer), rather than assigning what happens to be at the beginning of the allocated memory (which is uninitialized) to what `thing` points to (which is `a`).

So you'd need to do:

```
thing = (set_t *)malloc(sizeof(set_t)*N);
```

Otherwise, you're poking around at random memory locations when you assign via `*(thing+i)` which is a *Bad Thing*

Comment: I'm unable to do this because those change don't reflect to the original 'a' back in main()

Comment: Then you have to pass a _pointer_ to a _pointer_ to `a`.  This usually cause folks' heads to ache, and in worst case, explode. @dasblinkenlight's most recent answer gives the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. To conform to your professor's demands you would have to do something like this.

```
void init(set_t *thing, int N) {

    *thing = (set_t *)malloc(sizeof(set_t)*N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i = i + 1) {
        ((int *) *thing)[i] = i; // it's an array
    }

    return;
}
```

And then cast a to a pointer each time you try to get a value out of it. So:

```
((int *)a)[3]
```

Comment: I made the change and am still getting a segmentation fault :-/

Comment: Sorry. Fixed. I was testing without the function call.

Comment: I'm still getting the segmentation fault

Comment: Then you are probably in a 64 bit machine and can't cast ints to pointers. The reason this super hacky thing worked was due to ints and pointers occupying the same memory size (in 32 bit machines). That doesn't seem to be your case.

Comment: How come I can't cast in a 64 bit machine?

Comment: Because ints are 4 bytes long. Pointers are also 4 bytes long in a 32 bit machine. In a 64 bit, however, pointers are 8 bytes long. Different sizes leads to bad access, leads to seg fault.