# Convert a non-pointer variable to a pointer to an array

Tags: c, gcc

Ok, I understand that my title might be a bit confusing, but I'll explain. I'm working on a homework assignment in C. I'm given a .c file and need to come up with implementations for some functions.

In short, I have this as a .c file

```
typedef int set_t;
...
void init(set_t *a, int N); // Initialized an array to a of size N
...
int main() {
   set_t a;
   init(&a, 10);
}
```

In a couple of implementations I've come up with, I was able to create an array using a, but I keep getting segmentation faults when the program runs :-/. Is there away to initialize `a` as an array **without changing anything in the original .c file** except for the implementation of `init(set_t *a, int N)`?

**EDIT**

Here's my current implementation of init --> it leads to a segmentation fault

```
void init(set_t *a, int N) {

    //set_t thing[10];

    *a = malloc(sizeof(set_t)*N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        *(a + i) = i;
    }
    printf("value of a[2] = %d\n", a[2]);
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to show some of the body of `init()` — preferably all.  You'll need to make sure you're initializing memory properly; that your code is crashing suggests that you are not.  You do need to specify whether your functions can be changed; at the moment, the interface to `init()` does not look promising, but we need to know the constraints you're working under, if there are any.

Comment: I wish it was that easy. in the main function, `set_t a` can't change. I wish I could change it to `set_t *a` or `set_t a[10]`.

Comment: Can you reverify the definition of the `set_t` type; it is most odd to see a 'set' type defined thus.  I'm not sure there's a sane way to deal with the problem.  There are various insane ways, but those should not be used.  What code uses the initialized 'set of integers'?

Comment: Well to go into more detail... the problem is to compare the relative speed of intersections and unions of sets between a linked list and an array. So `a` will either be a linked list (where set_t is a structure with a head & tail) or an array (where set_t is an array of integers). The only reason I'm initializing the array is to see if everything gets passed from init back to main. Does this help?

Comment: If you used `a = malloc(sizeof(set_t) * N);` without the leading `*`, the code would run, and leak memory.  But the allocated memory would not be available in the `main()` program; the variable `a` in the main program can only hold a single `int`, not a pointer to an array of `int`.  On a 64-bit machine, `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)`, even, so things are really bad.

Comment: You said that `set_t` will either be a linked list or an array of integers.  But your `set_t` here is not an array of integers; it is a single integer.  That makes the problem insoluble.  Were it my code, I'd probably define the array-based type as a structure too: `typedef struct set_t { int *elements; int n_elements; } set_t;` or thereabouts (maybe it should record both the number of elements in use and the number allocated for use).  You can sort of make do without a size and `typedef int *set_t;`, but the code will be fragile since you won't know how big the set is.

Comment: Also, please note that clarifications should go into the question.  Many comments are best answered by updating the question rather than responding with another comment.

Comment: _EDIT 3_ : cause the movement to fire the professor(Because he/she go on to distribute the harm to people in education.) or you should study in self-education.

Comment: See also [Segmentation fault after program finishes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696672/segmentation-fault-after-program-finishes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Professor realized that he had made an error in the assignment and fixed it. Changed `set_t a` to `set_a *a`.

Thanks for all your help (hope I didn't cause too many headaches!

Answer (score 4):

As things currently stand, the requirements imposed on you are wholly unreasonable.  If you are building for 32-bit only, so `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int *)`, then you can use brutal casting to get around the constraints.  The code will not work on a 64-bit machine, though (unless `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int *)`, which isn't the case on any machine I can immediately think of.

So, the brute force and casting technique is:

```
void init(set_t *a, int N)
{
    assert(sizeof(set_t) == sizeof(set_t *));  // Ick, but necessary!
    set_t *base = malloc(sizeof(set_t)*N);
    if (base == 0)
        *a = 0;
    else
    {
        *a = (int)base;  // Brutal; non-portable; stupid; necessary by the rules given!
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            base[i] = i;
        printf("value of a[2] = %d\n", base[2]);
        printf("value of a[2] = %d\n", ((int *)*a)[2]);  // Brutal and stupid too
    }
}
```

Further, in the code in `main()`, you'll have to use `((int *)a)` to make the type usable for dereferencing, etc.  Without knowing about what is actually in that other code, it is impossible to be confident that anything will work.  It might, but it probably won't.

At this stage, this looks like someone criminally misleading innocent novice programmers.  This is not the way it should be coded at all.  However, if that's what the doctor (professor) orders, then that's what you've got to do.  But it is a mockery of good coding practices AFAICS and AFAIAC.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Unfortunately I'm working on a 64 bit machine. I'm going to have to stop by my professor's office Monday to figure out what's up

Comment: Compile with `-m32` if you're using GCC; that should compile it as 32-bit code even on a 64-bit machine.  :D  Yes, speak to the professor is a good idea.  There are other insane ways of dealing with it.  One is to use the value in `a` as a 'set descriptor' like a file descriptor; you create a new entry in an array of entries and return the index to the array.  However, that requires full support from functions that can treat the `int` as a 'set descriptor'; you won't be able to casually write `a[0]` in the `main()` program.

Comment: Oh, and if the prof comes up with a good answer, please let us know (add a comment here so I see that the extra information is available).  Thanks.

Comment: Professor realized that he had made an error in the assignment and fixed it. Changed `set_t a` to `set_a *a`. 

Thanks for all your help (hope I didn't cause too many headaches!

Comment: @TAD: That makes a lot more sense (whether it is `set_a *a` or `set_t *a`); you can work with that, I'm sure.  Phew!  I'm relieved for you that your prof realized that something was wrong and was ready to admit a mistake; I would have been worried otherwise.

Comment: Yes I can! Thanks again for all of your help!